# Merging two DOMDocument nodes

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Score</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2014</td>
    <td>3078</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I have the above table being successfully stored as a variable, how could I append it to a div with an overflow-x style attribute?

I've tried the following snippet but no cigar:

```
$div = str_get_html('<div style="overflow-x:auto;"></div>');

$div = $div->find('div');

$div = $div->appendChild($table);

return $div;
```

so expected output should be:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2014</td>
        <td>3078</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't you post the same question earlier?

Comment: @D.Wells Can you share your expected output?

Comment: @Sahil I've added it to the question now

Comment: _"I've tried the following snippet but no cigar:"_ - So what did you get? What is `return $table;` suppose to return in the first block? Is there code stripped out?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's just the table that I want to be enclosed in the div. If I return $table, it returns that table into the webpage.

Comment: You're making it hard for us to help you. If we have no idea what your current result/issue is, we can't really debug your code. You're also using "magic" variables (variables that we have no idea what they come from, how they got populated or what they contain), which we need to know to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this one will give you a basic idea of implementation. Here we are using `DOMDocument`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/855865)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//creating table node

$tableNode='<table><tr><th>Year</th><th>Score</th></tr><tr><td>2014</td><td>3078</td></tr></table>';

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->encoding="UTF-8";
$domDocument->loadHTML($tableNode);
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$table = $domXPath->query("//table")->item(0);

//creating empty div node.

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$element=$domDocument->createElement("div");
$element->setAttribute("style", "overflow-x:auto;");

$result=$domDocument->importNode($table,true);//importing node from of other DOMDocument
$element->appendChild($result);
echo $domDocument->saveHTML($element);
```